# Convert txt file list of items into the actual code for creating an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

to start i am terrible with loops and arrays.

I have a txt file that i can turn into an array using file() but **i need to pull the data from the text file into my code to create the code for making an array, not put the data into an actual array.**

i need to turn:

```
cat
dog
mouse
```

into the following code dynamically (**i do not need to make an actual outputted array**, i need to create the code dynamically somehow).:

```
Array('cat'=>'cat','dog'=>'dog','mouse'=>'mouse')
```

My problem is that i need to do the following:

txt file input:

```
Crafts & Sewing\Sale\Sale\Sale on Crafts & Sewing
Crafts & Sewing\Sale\Sale\Crafts & Sewing Sale
```

Each item is on a seperate line of the txt file (over 10k lines)

Output (not browser output, still in code):

```
$somevariable = Array('line1' => 'line1', 'line2' => 'line2')
```

But everything i try gives me the actual array.

**I need to create the actual CODE** for an array by taking each line of the text file and pulling it into my code and adding in the commas, and quotes, and => without actually going through and manually adding that all to 10k lines of code.

basically i have a HUGE list in a text file and instead of going through and manually adding and editing over 10k lines of the text file to be in that format and then cluttering up my code with that, i want to put it all into the correct format programatically and then just use that variable in my code rather than 10k lines of code. This also allows me to edit the text file with new content whenever it changes without needing to edit the code.

I am using it to create a dropdown in a site that take the format as follows:

```
array(
    'id'  => 'quality',
    'type' => 'select',
    'label' => __('Quality', 'esc_vff'),
    'options' => array(
        'New'  => 'New',
        'Used'  => 'Used',
        'Refurbished' => 'Refurbished'              
    ),
    'description' => __('Overstock data for "Quality" column.', 'esc_vff'),
    'desc_tip'    => true,
)
```

in the end i would like to be able to do something like change:

```
'options' => array(
    'New' => 'New',
    'Used' => 'Used',
    'Refurbished' => 'Refurbished'              
),
```

to:

```
'options' => $myarrayfromtextfile,
```

where $myarrayfromtextfile is a variable or something that gives me the code that should be put there, but isnt 10k lines of code.

maybe to better clarify:  an array printed out has the brackets... i need to find a way to print out the code structure of the array (i dunno if thats the best way to word this)    because i am taking a bunch of lines of text and trying to format it to look like i went through and wrote the comma seperated code version of the array

```
array('foo' => 'foo' , 'bar' => 'bar' )
```

so i need a variable that when dropped into another array gets compiled/converted to the physical code structure, not the final browser rendered array with length counts and brackets...

Or ill take any other ideas on how to make 10k lines of text end up looking like

```
 array('foo' => 'foo' , 'bar' => 'bar' )
```

without going line by line adding in commas and => and ''

Comment: I feel like i need to do something involving  array($line[$i],$line[$i]) and then some sore of for each with an i++ before that so that i pull each line of the text file in and it creates the code for array()
but it all ends up inside the larger parent array so im not sure its even possible or if im going to just need to go through 10k lines of text and add in the commas and quotes and => and just include() the file as php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php ***[file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)***

File — Reads entire file into an array

```
<?php 
$lines = file('test.txt'); ///path to your file
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
{
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

**As per your requirement**

```
<?php 
$lines = file('test.txt'); ///path to you file
$arrayVar = "array(";
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
{
    $arrayVar.= "'".preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $line)."' => '".preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $line)."',";
}
$arrayVar = rtrim($arrayVar,',').');';
echo $arrayVar;
?>
```

I have this in my test.txt file

```
abc
cde
efg
hij
klm
```

The code above will give you array like this in your browser

```
array('abc' => 'abc','cde' => 'cde','efg' => 'efg','hij' => 'hij','klm' => 'klm');
```

Is this you want? **@HostandMore**

Comment: ignore my last comment, i think this works.. ill test and get back.. i didnt let the page fully load. i just need to grasp putting the whole thing into one variable that i can put in that other code, i am terrible with oop and arrays and stuff, gimme a min and ill com back and vote this up once im done.

Comment: no dice, this is just outputting the line number a colon and then the line..  

i need to keep it as an array, just formatted with commas and single quotes instead of the bracketted array format. if that makes sense.

Comment: i added some more clarification.. i need some code that will convert a bunch of lines of text in a file into the actual code version of an array.. not the object version...  my terminology is terrible i know.

Comment: @HostandMore I think you want to print the array in browser as it looks in code...

Comment: @HostandMore I've added a code for you in my answer try this ;)

Comment: YES. i can work with that. now to find out if i can use a variable inside another array and have it work LOL

Comment: well thank you for the work, but i dont think it will end up working for what i need. BUT your code does exactly what i was looking for.. but it seems i cannot put the variable into the larger array and have it parse correctly.. ill keep at it though.

Comment: i got it!  basically i used the code you gave me and output it to a file and then i was able to edit the file and add the beginning and end of the array code that i needed.. BAM  i now have a dropdown with 10k options without having to code 10k lines :)

THANK YOU

Comment: @HostandMore, You can use  the array directly in drop down options array, there is no need to print array and then paste it in options. Anyways glad to help you;) you can up vote my answer now ;)

Comment: i cant at the moment, it throws an error as improper format. But for now i dumped the output to a filed and added the whopping 5-10 lines of code to make it into a function including its parent array. i had to find and replace to manually escape some things because there apparently are apostrophes in some of the lines to show possession like  Boy**bold**'**bold**s so i suspect that if when i have a minute take some time to tweak your code to account for that it will probably work.

Comment: i also can only check your answer as i do not have 15 points of rep yet to upvote :(

Comment: its okay dear no worries 

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array();
$f = file('file.txt');
foreach ($f as $n => $l) 
{
    $a["Line {$n}"] = $l;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: this gives me $l which is just the final line of the text file.

i am trying to get $variable = Array('line1' => 'line1' , 'line2' => 'line2' , 'line3' => 'line3')

exactly like that so that if i echoed or printed(whichever does arrays) i would see    the first like surrounded by single quotes then an => then the first line again in quotes, then a comma to separate the next set.

does this make sense?? i also could just be messing up the implementation of your code.

Comment: i added some more clarification.. i need some code that will convert a bunch of lines of text in a file into the actual code version of an array.. not the object version... my terminology is terrible i know.

Comment: Meaning that i want to pull the data that is in the text file into my code to be used as code itself, i just dont want to go through all 10k lines of text and add the commas and => and single quotes in side of array()..  i am not trying to output the text file as an actual array, but rather out put it as code that is the same as if i manually went through and wrote array(with 10k comma seperated items in it)

Comment: I think based on your first comment, the variable $a is what you are looking for. In my opinion that should work, otherwise please provide a sample file to test this my code.

Comment: your code outputs a final product that is shown by the browser.. i edited my question.. i need to output actual code.

meaning i need the text file to become code inside of the rest of my code, technically it would end up inside another array.

'options' => array(
    'New' => 'New',
    'Used' => 'Used',
    'Refurbished' => 'Refurbished'              
),

this code here is part of the array of options.. where used and refurbished and new are options.. i need to create this code dynamically from the text file or i have to edit 10k lines of text to be in the correct code format

Comment: in other words a file to test teh code wouldnt help because i do not need the code to output anything.. i need code that will create more code from the text file, i have the code to make it into an actual array, but in order to do that i would need to go and edit all 10k lines of text, 24 lines in another file, and manually add the commas and => etc into it to create the code i need... i want to automate that.. so the code should output more code, not an actual array, but the code for one.